Can't change the citation key formula in Better BibTeX in Zotero
I am currently using Zotero 7 on MacOS with the Better BibTeX plugin. I’m trying to customize the citation key formula, but I am unable to change the active citation key formula in the Better BibTeX settings.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I went to Preferences > Better BibTeX and modified the Citation key formula under Citation keys. Specifically, I want to change the formula to auth.lower + year (or similar), but the active citation key formula remains unchanged even after I apply the changes.
I tried regenerating the citation keys for individual entries by right-clicking and selecting Better BibTeX → Regenerate citation keys, but the citation keys still follow the old (default) formula.
I restarted Zotero after making the changes, but the formula is still not updating.
I also tried checking Zotero’s Config Editor for any settings related to Better BibTeX, but I couldn’t find anything that would let me unlock or manually adjust the citation key formula.
I’ve tried reinstalling Better BibTeX, and I’ve verified that no other Zotero add-ons are interfering with the process.

It feels like the active citation key formula is somehow locked by default or otherwise resistant to changes, and I can’t seem to find a way to override or manually force the update.


How is this a programming question?

You need to refresh the BibTex Key.
Right-click on the citation you would like to export and then:
better BibTex -> Refresh BibTex Key.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
